# Is it possible to reset locale to the portable locale?

Tags: python, locale, python-2.4

According to the Python documentation:

> "a program which has not called `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')` runs using the portable 'C' locale.

After having set the locale with `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')` is it possible to reset the locale back to the "portable" state? I work on a library which includes some misbehaved components which attempt to globally reset the locale to the region specific - I need to find a way to revert the locale back to the portable state.

```
import locale
loc = locale.getlocale(locale.LC_ALL) # get current locale
assert loc == (None, None)
# Locale is unset, therefore in the "portable" state.
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') # use user's preferred locale
# Loc is not set to regional default
???? DO SOMETHING HERE
assert loc == locale.getlocale(locale.LC_ALL) # I want to make this true!
```

Needs to work on Python 2.4.4 on Windows XP 32bit

Answer (score 4):

You could try: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, loc)`.

```
>>> locale.getlocale(locale.LC_ALL)
(None, None)
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")                                        
'en_US.utf8'
>>> locale.getlocale(locale.LC_ALL)
('en_US', 'UTF8')
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "C")                                   
'C'
>>> locale.getlocale(locale.LC_ALL)
(None, None)
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, (None,None))
'C'
>>> locale.getlocale(locale.LC_ALL)
(None, None)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
locale.setlocale(locale.getdefaultlocale())
```

Will set it back to the standard locale